# Find shortest paths through predefined set of vertices and edges in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

I need to find shortest paths which should pass through several nodes and edges. Few details:

1. It should be shortest paths according to weights.
2. Include set can be ordered and unordered.
3. Graph size - 50 000 vertices and 450 0000 edges

Is there any way to find paths like this using arangodb?
I've tried K_SHORTEST_PATHS but it is too slow for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Without a data set, this is tricky to test.  Unfortunately, `K_SHORTEST_PATHS` is the only built-in way to add "weight" to edges, unless you build something yourself.  Also, both `SHORTEST_PATH` methods do not implement `PRUNE`, which is the best way to speed graph traversal.

My suggestion would be to use a directed graph method (`FOR v,e,p IN 1..9 INBOUND x...`), implementing both `PRUNE` and `FILTER` clauses to reduce the number of hops, and something like `COLLECT path = p AGGREGATE weight = SUM(e.weight)` to calculate weight.